# apache echarts - How do I move left the markline?

Tags: echarts

I'm referring to [this example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=pie-borderRadius&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsA2BTA5l6AJgFzIC-ANGrGMMBpCCUhVQQIZhsDOWYTV6LsACuAJwDGWEgG0B6WNIBEIUcALDxYReViKATAAYAjAFZtuw0YBs5_cYDsigLqV58pQFkO4gBZtYADIcYFjmACwAzAB0EToAHCZRcToAnNH2LnLonhAYANawACpYbOZx0UY69tFhOiaJRplu2YoAwj5YWDywrcDiwKXxVlG1sFaJevF6USZNzUoA6mwY0MJgsABCqgDu0BChVdOjJtEpOhEpUY1yTlQs6AAeAIIPEFz8bmAAniBSuuIcXDAURfbRyLggDAQMABCDQP6oZqwLg-YDbEhgUTCLCuZpQ-EAZW-2A-SNg_QwwJIigAxAZ6YosrBSHIWeh7rAvi83kwOTxRPt3go5Ijmt9ftSAEZsURgpEAWxleVh8NJSPxWCJXxJyFg2wgBDAPhIsXJdCpsAA5KIsARLczcUiuF95ZK6DJLeIIBJsJadJboDAsJa5kj2JwZEy3NJdf1gcQFAYdIYnA7Y7RRAnpJVYCnmbBQ2SY0gzfGZDmwgZUxR02WFJNYJXqwXHc1bki2fIOegS-K_oppbKHSLqD9-4PFMyqLdSABuIA) to draw marklines...

It works great but I want it to fit inside x category.

How can I deal with this, the **to-be** line?

Floting point is not working as expected though..

```
                  data: [
                    [ { coord: [-0.5, 20] }, { coord: [0.5, 20] } ], // not working...
                    [ { coord: [0.5, 40] }, { coord: [1.5, 40] } ],
                  ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved!
The magic is `xAxisIndex`. :)